# How to float a div over Google Maps?

Tags: html, css, google-maps

I have a `div` that displays a Google map.

How do I make another `div` float over the map `div`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [div on top of div with Google Maps API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786967/div-on-top-of-div-with-google-maps-api)

Answer (score 149, accepted):

Try this:

```
<style>
   #wrapper { position: relative; }
   #over_map { position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 10px; z-index: 99; }
</style>

<div id="wrapper">
   <div id="google_map">

   </div>

   <div id="over_map">

   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is that cross-browser ? IE6 ? 7 ?

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work I need my events to bubble up to Google Maps.

Comment: this has nothing to do with event bubbling, it is just basic css. And yeah, it is cross-browser, position absolute and relative is ancient.

Comment: What in case if we use bootstrap column grid system and when we want content to be in front of the map? For example, https://jsfiddle.net/y30am49b/1/ ... whether is proper way to add position absolute to container-fluid or col-xs-4 in this case?

Comment: But that doesn't work when you go full screen. Is there any workaround for that?

Answer (score 15):

```
#floating-panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 25%;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Just need to move the map below this box. Work to me.

From Google

Comment: This was the only one in the list that worked for me. Thanks dude

Answer (score 4):

Just set the position of the div and you may have to set the z-index.

ex.

```
div#map-div {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
}
div#cover-div {
    position:absolute;
    left:10px;
    top: 10px;
    z-index:3;
}
```

Answer (score -12):

absolute positioning is evil... this solution doesn't take into account window size. If you resize the browser window, your div will be out of place!

Comment: You are talking about fixed positioning, not absolute.

Comment: Not if you use it correctly, you need to make sure your absolute positioned element is inside a relative positioned element, otherwise your absolutely positioned elements is positioned in relation to the viewport size.