# Remove/Edit Google's link on Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

Is there a way of removing or editing the white bottom-left "Google" link in a Street View panorama? I don't mind that it is there as long as it doesn't link back to the coordinates of the place it's showing. I'm making a game where the person has to guess the location being shown and this ruins the whole point of it. I already removed the address via `addressControl: false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come up with a solution based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6037712/how-to-float-a-div-over-google-maps). The idea is to put a `div` above the undesired part that is transparent and links back to Google Maps. Tested on Chrome and Safari:

```html
<div id="google_map" style="width: 600px; height: 430px; margin-bottom: -30px"></div>
<div style="width: 70px; position: relative; z-index: 1;">
  <a style="display: block; width: 70px; height: 30px" href="http://maps.google.com/"></a>   
</div>
```

**NOTE:** The `div` can, of course, be easily deleted by the user.

Answer (score 2):

Not using a Street View Panorama there isn't, but maybe instead you want to use the [Street View Image API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/streetview/).