# Float a div over google maps while maintaining bootstrap responsiveness

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps

I'm trying to over lay a bootstrap container over google maps.

Referring to : [How to float a div over Google Maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6037712/how-to-float-a-div-over-google-maps)

I've managed to overlay a div over google maps using the above method. However, it is doing so by using absolute positioning within a relative-positioned wrapper to achieve that. That means that the overlay is not responsive. Is there a way I can overlay responsive bootstrap classes over google map? Thanks.

Comment: i think you are looking for this http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/qp2tu5e4/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The map can be positioned absolutely and the container can be positioned relatively over the map.

```
<div id="content">
<div id="gmap"></div>
<div class="container overlap"></div>
</div>

#gmap {position:absolute;top:0;left:0;}
.overlap {position:relative}
```

see here in a pen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/sojbd