# z-index CSS, button over Google maps

Tags: html, css, cordova, google-maps-api-3

I want to put a button "select " on the map above to the top centre.But when I write the " div " in CSS like this:

```
.over
{
z-index: 2;
position: top center;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 20px;

}

#map-canvas
   { 
    height: 550px;
    width: 100%;   
    padding-top: 0px;
    margin: 0px; 

   }
```

Does not work , you see under the map. The " Div " the google map does not have a z -index within

Comment: Could you add the html (and js) as well. Including the Google maps part?

Comment: No, I'm just a CSS code you run, you do not need the rest .
Map call with < div id = map - canvas> < / div >

Comment: Saw something that might help [**how to float div over google map**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6037712/how-to-float-a-div-over-google-maps).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the button as a [custom control](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#CustomPositioning).