# How to load a <div> on top of React google map component?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-google-maps

I am trying to display a small card basically over the google maps component that this https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-google-maps/api package provides. I set the zIndex to 2 but the `<div>` still shows below this map component.

The card element is not supposed to respond to any click it's just displayed on first load with the Map component

```
  return (
    <div>
      <GoogleMap
        mapContainerStyle={mapContainerStyle}
        zoom={8}
        center={center}
      ></GoogleMap>
      <Tracking style={{zIndex: 2}}/>
    </div>
  );
```

Tracking is the div that contains information.

Map container style is:

```
const mapContainerStyle = {
  width: "100vw",
  height: "100vh",
};
```

Comment: Can you share what code you have so far?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6037712/how-to-float-a-div-over-google-maps

Comment: Check the re-edit I put some return code. I set the zindex to 2 so that it displays over but is coming down

Comment: @Abidi I already tried that I put my return div as a wrapper in this example and gave position absolute to the tracking component and still it comes down below

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there are a lot of ways to do it.

Briefly:

1. You have to add `position: 'relative'` to the parent component.
2. You have to add `position: 'absolute'` and `zIndex: 0` to the child component that you want to display as the background.
3. You have to add `position: 'absolute'` and `zIndex: 1` (or more) to the child component that you want to display as the foreground.

If you use inline styling, you could do this:

Adding `top: some_number`, `left: some_number`, `right: some_number`, or `bottom: some_number` is optional (depends on what position you want)

Here is the working code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-rhodes-qbm43

App.js

```js
import "./styles.css";
import Map from "./Map.js";
import Tracking from "./Tracking";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        position: "absolute",
        zIndex: 0,
        width: "100%", // or you can use width: '100vw'
        height: "100%" // or you can use height: '100vh'
      }}
    >
      <Map />
      <div
        style={{
          zIndex: 1,
          position: "absolute",
          top: 10,
          left: 10,
          backgroundColor: "white", // you can use any color value
          width: "10%", // or you can use width: any_number
          height: "90%" // or you can use height: any_number
        }}
      >
        <Tracking />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Map.js

```js
import React from "react";
import {
  GoogleMap,
  useLoadScript,
  Marker,
  InfoWindow
} from "@react-google-maps/api";
import Tracking from "./Tracking";
const libraries = ["places"];

const mapContainerStyle = {
  position: "relative",
  width: "100%",
  height: "100%"
};

const center = {
  lat: -33.86882,
  lng: 151.20929
};

function Map() {
  const { isLoaded, loadError } = useLoadScript({
    googleMapsApiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY,
    libraries
  });

  if (loadError) return "Error loading maps";
  if (!isLoaded) return "Loading Maps";
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        position: "absolute",
        zIndex: 0,
        width: "100%", // or you can use width: '100vw'
        height: "100%" // or you can use height: '100vh'
      }}
    >
      <GoogleMap
        mapContainerStyle={mapContainerStyle}
        zoom={8}
        center={center}
      ></GoogleMap>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Map;
```

Tracking.js

```js
import React from "react";

const Tracking = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    </div>
  );
};

export default Tracking;
```

Comment: what about using ```zIndex``` with a big number (more than 2), example ```zIndex: 99```?

Comment: It still comes below the map even after zIndex: 99

Comment: I did exactly this and the map is completely gone it is only displaying the Tracking Component

Comment: could you please create a fiddle or code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/ for me? so I can edit and run it directly

Comment: The second edit was when the map was gone completely and with this third edit, the div is still coming down below.

Comment: I have updated the answer by providing you the codesandbox