# setting div attributes of google map api v3 markers

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I've been trying to set `<div id="myMarker">` or `<div class="myClass">`attributes of google map markers so that I can later apply CSS formatting to them.

I understand that `google.maps.Marker` class are extension of the `MVCObject` so I use for example:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);
marker.set('id', 'myMarker');
console.log(marker.get('id');
```

Everything is good the property id is set as shown in console log. In fact, I don't even have to use `.set()` I can write it directly in `markerOptions`. Anyways, when I do a div inspection I see that the property I set, in this case `id="myMarker"` , does not appear in the  marker markup as I intended. In other words, indeed `marker` has a property key named `id` whose value is `myMarker` but it is not the `<div id="myMarker">` that I intent to produce for later css formatting.

I have seen that every marker belongs to a  element that is usually referenced by the title attribute. I am wondering if there is a more straightforward way to do that (such as a class or an Id).

So I'm stuck in figuring this out since a similar question in SO indicates `.set(key,value)` works. Indeed it works for setting a property but this property however is not inserted as html markup for later referencing and formatting. Any lights shed would be most helpful.
Regards.

Comment: There aren't any documented methods to do that.  If you want to add access to the id & class of a "marker" on your map, you need to create a custom marker using a [Custom Overlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/customoverlays).  Possibly relevant question: [Replace Markers by html content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918995/replace-markers-by-html-content)

Comment: So the most straight forward way is for example to load the markers as geojson layer with a property called `"id":"myMaker"` and then find the corresponding marker by checking the geojson data? Thank you for the reply @geocodezip